# Why does Twitter say my status update is over 140 characters when I only posted 130?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, twitter

I've been able to tweet hundreds of times on iOS, but I've run into one tweet that I just can't tweet out. This tweet is only 130 characters, but Twitter responds claiming that it is over 140 characters. So Twitter won't post it.

**Relevant code:**

```
- (void)tweet:(NSString *)message
{
    SLRequest* request = [SLRequest
        requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
        requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
        URL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:
            @"%@statuses/update.json",
            API_BASE_URL
        ]]
        parameters:@{
            @"status": message
        }
    ];
    request.account = self.context.account;
    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *eror) {
        if (responseData != nil) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        }
     ];
}
```

**Console printouts:**

```
(lldb) po message
@juandoming Dallas teachers improved student performance by 20% w/mobile video messaging. Would this be useful to you? Ccccccc.com

(lldb) p message.length
(unsigned int) $1 = 130
2014-09-11 12:25:01.326 app[1685:6b13] {"errors":[{"code":186,"message":"Status is over 140 characters."}]}
(lldb)
```

The actual URL is not Ccccccc.com, but it has the same number of characters.

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with the URL, perhaps they are trying to t.co-ify the link or something? Try replacing the URL with the same amount of text and see if the problem still exists..

Comment: is there no way to get back the transformed message? seems like something is modifying the original such as adding `http://` etc

Comment: I don't believe the URL is being transformed. When the posting is successful, my URL appears unaltered.

Comment: Correction: The URL *appears* unaltered, but when I hover over it, I see that it was converted to a 22 character t.co/XXX url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your URL is probably counting as 20 characters.

https://twittercommunity.com/t/getting-the-text-of-your-tweet-is-too-long-error-with-140-character-tweets/13307

"For all intents and purposes, all URLs and most things that look like URLs should essentially be considered 20 characters long when composing a tweet. Clients and sites that render t.co links properly make this process mostly transparent -- you'll see a representation of your original bit.ly link in the UI, but underneath it's still been wrapped with t.co."

Comment: My URL was converted to a super long http://t.co/XXXXXXXXXXXXX of not 20 characters, but 22 characters! To the naked eye, it appears that my URL is unaltered, but if I hover over it with my mouse, I can see the true t.co URL. Wow! Twitter's URL shortening service is actually a lengthening service.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the twitter count characters in a different way. 
Twitter uses Unicode, UTF-8 more specifically, and to count the characters the Twitter counts the number of bytes in order to make a character 
here`s the documentation link: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/counting-characters

In order to solve this problem, Twitter made a library with some function really useful. 
https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text
the supported languages are Java, Ruby, JavaScript, and Objective-C

Here is how I got the length of the tweet and solve the problem of Tweet needs to be a bit shorter.

```
const twitterText = require('twitter-text')
twitterText.parseTweet(YOURTWEET).weightedLength
```